# pushbullet and OAuth

Tags: oauth, pushbullet

I have a simple question about using Pushbullet's OAuth API and was not able to find the answer on PUshbullet's site. Specifically, if I register my client app to use Pushbullet's OAuth authentication and I send my users to give their approval to allow me to use their Pushbullet's credentials, what happens if the person is not already a Pushbullet user? Will they be allowed to register themselves with Pushbullet as a new user (**I hope!**) AND then be redirected back to my app, or will that kind of break the OAuth flow? I am trying to use Pushbullet as my notifications mechanism for my mobile hybrid app and it seems like it is a great fit, but I know many of my users will not know how to recover if they break out of being redirected back to my web app. TIA.

JLP

Answer (score 0):

New users should be redirected to your app. You should test it yourself to make sure though.